# QueryDSL SQL. Char Y/N database field to boolean attribute in model

Tags: java, dao, querydsl

I am using the SQL version of QueryDSL and it's code generator to build my Q-Classes and  the corresponding Java POJOS from the database.

Using a legacy database (Firebird) we have some database `CHAR(1)` columns treated as **boolean** whose domain is `'Y`' and `'N'`. Is there any way when projecting these columns to my model attributes to automatically map or convert these Y/N values to a boolean Java type?

Answer (score 1):

querydsl-sql will return the type mapped by the JDBC driver being used. I would suggest using `Projections.constructor` to instantiate your POJO and have a getter that returns a `boolean` as follows:

```
List<Pojo> pojos = query
                  .select(Projections.constructor(Pojo.class, qtable.yesNoValue))
                  .fetch();

public class Pojo {

    private final String yesNoValue;

    public Pojo(String yesNoValue) {
        this.yesNoValue = yesNoValue;
    }

    public boolean getYesNoValue() {
        return "Y".equals(yesNoValue);
    }

}
```

Similarly, you could create a concrete instance of `com.querydsl.core.types.MappingProjection`, overriding `protected abstract T map(Tuple row)` to instantiate your POJO with the desired types.